# Locally parsing PHP in the browser

Tags: php

I'm looking for a recommendation as to the best way of parsing PHP locally. Is there an add-on for Google Chrome that would mean I don't have to host a file in order to run the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is executed by the PHP processor, not your browser.

You need to have a webserver and PHP running on your local machine. On Windows, [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is a popular (and easy) way to get this development stack up and running.

You can find any number of tutorials for getting the LAMP stack setup on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Just install a webserver. [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) is a good choice or, if you're under Windows, you can also consider IIS.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. PHP is a server-side scripting language.

As an aside, *parsing* PHP would be possible in the browser. *Executing the code* would not.

Comment: But if I was hosting locally would my computer not act as the server?

Comment: @It would: but still, PHP code would be executed inside a *web server* process, not inside your browser. There are lots of "ready to go" packages which install Apache + PHP + MySql for you painlessly. I 've used `EasyPHP` with no problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome I don't know, but you can run php from the command line, run a local server (if you're on Windows, Wamp or Xamp are easy to install). And several IDE's (NetBeans php for one) have the option of executing files locally from your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)? It's easy to install, maintain, use as a debugging environment. If you have a spare computer laying around, you may also consider setting up a dedicated testing server with a Ubuntu LiveCD. There's a bit of a learner's curve if your used to Window's GUI, but you can do some amazing things with a Linux box.
Once you setup a server, you can point to it in Chrome with it's LAN IP or with http://localhost/ (if you installed XAMPP on your computer).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project: http://phpjs.hertzen.com/
(This is for People who stumbled over this Question via Goole)

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: I am the author.]

Uniter allows you to parse and execute PHP in the browser (or Node.js.)

http://asmblah.github.io/uniter/

Example code could be like the following:

```
require([
    'uniter'
], function (
    uniter
) {
    'use strict';

    var phpEngine = uniter.createEngine('PHP');

    function output() {
        console.log(phpEngine.getStdout().readAll());
        console.log(phpEngine.getStderr().readAll());
    }

    phpEngine.expose({
        number1: 7
    }, 'myData');

    phpEngine.execute('<?php return $myData->number1 + 2;').done(function (value) {
        output();

        console.log('Result: ' + value);
    }).fail(function (exception) {
        output();
    });
});
```